# Use of "in" and span of time; "prior" and specific date

Tags: meaning, prepositions, dates

I am trying to accomplish an application, and one of the requirements is to complete/finish your studies (i.e. graduate and get your degree). I don't understand the way they worded it. They use this phrase:

> All applications must satisfy the study requirement **in the six months immediately prior to making their application**.

In another part, they have this question:

> Have you met the study requirement **in the six months before the date of application**?

Does this mean that I should apply no more than six months **AFTER** I complete the study requirement or that I can apply **BEFORE** I complete the study requirement but I should be able to complete the degree **WITHIN** six months from when I first made my application?

Comment: "All applications must satisfy" or "All applicants must satisfy"?

Comment: The words "before" and "prior" seem to be very clear about the required ordering. Why is this a question?

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, these two sentences are a bit confusing.  But, in this context "in the six months prior" has the same meaning as "during the six months prior."  To answer your questions specifically:

> Does this mean that I should apply no more than six months AFTER I
>   complete the study requirement.

**Yes.**

> Or that I can apply BEFORE I complete the study requirement but I
>   should be able to complete the degree WITHIN six months from when I
>   first made my application?

**No.** If this was true, the sentence would read "All [applicants] must satisfy the study requirement within six months of making their application." That would suggest a window of 6 months before and after application.

The key is to look at the words **prior** and **before**. Both sentences say you must complete all requirements before or prior to applying.

> All applications must **satisfy the study requirement** in the six months immediately **prior to making their application**.
>
> Have you **met the study requirement** in the six months **before the
>   date of application?**

You must complete all study requirements **before** application.  But after you finish those requirements, you need to apply within 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

applications in your first sentence doesn't seem logical. It would be applicants. So I cannot make any comment for the first sentence. As far as I understand from the second sentence, there is some study requirement and these should be completed, so it is asked that did you complete (met) the these requirements within 6 months before the date of application.

But both of them have lack of meaning.

Comment: Use of "application" rather than "applicant" in the first sentence seems to be a metonym.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rule that you cite, study requirements come first, then application. Your first sentence matches this order of events: "I should apply no more than six months AFTER I complete the study requirement."